# Gretty configuration doesn't applied when using farmRun task

Tags: gradle, gretty

I'm using the Gretty sample from: https://github.com/gretty-gradle-plugin/gretty-sample 
In master build.gradle I modified only repositories URLs (to use mirror repo due proxy):

**build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            //url 'http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local/'
            url 'http://10.0.0.1:7003/nexus/content/groups/public/'
        }
        //jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.gretty:gretty:+' 
    }
}

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'war'
    apply plugin: 'org.gretty'

    gretty {
        scanInterval = 1 //Scan for changes every second
        host = '0.0.0.0' //Enable network access from outside your local machine
        httpPort = 8011
        servletContainer = 'jetty7' //Use Jetty7 which is compatible with JDK6
        managedClassReload = true //Activate spring-loaded class reloading
        integrationTestTask = 'integrationTest'
    }

    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8
    version = '1.0'

repositories {
    maven {
        //url 'http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local/'
        url 'http://10.0.0.1:7003/nexus/content/groups/public/'
    }
    //jcenter()
}

}

apply plugin: 'org.gretty'

farm {
    webapp ':customer'
    webapp ':car'
}

repositories {
    maven {
        //url 'http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local/'
        url 'http://10.0.0.1:7003/nexus/content/groups/public/'
    }
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

you can see the port is specified as:

> httpPort = 8011

under subprojects section. When I run the gradle

> gradlew :farmRun

it reports:

```
17:38:42 INFO  Jetty 9.2.26.v20180806 started and listening on port 8080
17:38:42 INFO  customer runs at:
17:38:42 INFO    http://localhost:8080/customer
17:38:42 INFO  car runs at:
17:38:42 INFO    http://localhost:8080/car

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':farmRun'.
> java.lang.Exception: Address already in use: bind
```

so the jetty is still trying to use default port 8080. Thank you for any hints.

Comment: I checked some of the basic reasons of this issues listed as result: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Address+already+in+use+jetty (as. e.g. forgotten .ini /.xml configuration for Jetty)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method **subprojects** is NOT called by :farmRun. The **gretty** configuration method needs to be on root layer or directly part of **farm** method.

```
farm {
    webapp ':customer'
    webapp ':car'

    gretty {
        httpPort = 8012
        servletContainer = 'jetty7' //Use Jetty7 which is compatible with JDK6
        managedClassReload = true //Activate spring-loaded class reloading
    }
}
```